# Does Haxe pickup on typedefs in interfaces and classes?

Tags: haxe

If I declare a typedef in a class or interface, can classes that import/implement the class/interface use the typedef?

Comment: What do you mean by "pickup on the typedef"? Also, typedefs can only exist in the top-level, out of any class/interface definition.

Answer (score 2):

You import a module, which can have a list of typedefs and direct definitions in it(and MUST have one definition with the same name as module). If definition isn't marked as private, it will be imported in your scope and you will be able to use it(with or without namespace).